# PING between Database Server & App Server - Ping from App Server is Request TimeOut But Ping from DB Server is Success

Tags: windows, ping

I have a Database Server and Application Server. Application Server is hosted with an application that has been fetching data from DB server. This is working fine but when I tried to ping DB server from App server I always get Request Time Out, on the other hand if I ping App Server in the DB server it is succeeding. So my question, For a successful connection between two servers, either way is enough or both is fine? If both way success required, then how come my db data is showing in application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re referring to different protocols.

For `ping` to be successful, the source computer will send an ICMP Echo Request and the destination computer will respond with an ICMP Echo Reply.

ICMP is a different protocol from TCP which your application uses to communicate with the database.

The two are unrelated. ICMP can be blocked without affecting communication with a database server.

Check the firewall settings on the DB server to make sure it allows ICMP Echo Requests inbound, and ICMP Echo Replies outbound.

Comment: This is where tcping from the Sysinternals suite is useful.

Comment: Thank  you for the answer and I tried `PSPING.exe IP: DBport` and that showing success :)